# How to store dark mode in session storage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am implementing dark mode on my website. I am trying to store the user preference as a session storage but my code does not work.

```
onload = function() {
if(sessionStorage.getItem("darkmode") === "true") {
    sessionStorage.getItem("darkmode");
            $( "body" ).addClass( "dark" );
            $("#switch").addClass("switched");
            sessionStorage.setItem("darkMode", "true");
   }
}


 (function($) { "use strict";

$(function() {
    var header = $(".start-style");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 10) {
            header.removeClass('start-style').addClass("scroll-on");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("scroll-on").addClass('start-style');
        }
    });
});

//Animation
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body.hero-anime').removeClass('hero-anime');
});

//Menu On Hover
$('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave','.nav-item',function(e){
        if ($(window).width() > 750) {
            var _d=$(e.target).closest('.nav-item');_d.addClass('show');
            setTimeout(function(){
            _d[_d.is(':hover')?'addClass':'removeClass']('show');
            },1);
        }
});

//Switch light/dark
$("#switch").on('click', function() {
    if ($("body").hasClass("dark")) {
        //removes dark mode
        $("body").removeClass("dark");
        $("#switch").removeClass("switched");
        sessionStorage.setItem('darkmode', 'false');
    }
    else {
        $("body").addClass("dark");
        $("#switch").addClass("switched");
        sessionStorage.setItem('darkmode', 'true');
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

I have tried using localStorage before but there is a delay when refreshing the page before dark mode activates.

Comment: _"there is a delay when refreshing the page before dark mode activates."_ That's because your code is wrapped in an `onload` event. It waits until the page is fully loaded (images and all) to run

Comment: Ok. So should it just be:

if(sessionStorage.getItem("darkmode") === "true") {
    sessionStorage.getItem("darkmode");
            $( "body" ).addClass( "dark" );
            $("#switch").addClass("switched");
            sessionStorage.setItem("darkMode", "true");
   }
}

Comment: Well, you have too much code here, but in essence, yes. Try changing the mode here, and reloading: https://jsfiddle.net/2yx8apus/

Comment: It works. There is still a slight delay though.

Comment: What you could try to get rid of the delay: put [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/9tLS52Rc) right after the opening `<body>` tag. _(sorry I edited that link, make sure you have that version. And don't forget to change `localStorage` to `sessionStorage`, if you want to "forget" about that setting when the user closes his browser)_

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the problem that you used `===` sign and when you set the value of `darkmode` you assigned it 'true' but you checked if it is  "true", so these two things are not same if you use `===` sign.

I think you can write like this:

Set value:

```
//Switch light/dark
$("#switch").on('click', function() {
    if ($("body").hasClass("dark")) {
        //removes dark mode
        $("body").removeClass("dark");
        $("#switch").removeClass("switched");
        sessionStorage.setItem("darkmode", false);
    }
    else {
        $("body").addClass("dark");
        $("#switch").addClass("switched");
        sessionStorage.setItem("darkmode", true);
    }
});
```

Check value:

```
onload = function() {
if(sessionStorage.getItem("darkmode")) {
    sessionStorage.getItem("darkmode");
            $( "body" ).addClass( "dark" );
            $("#switch").addClass("switched");
            sessionStorage.setItem("darkMode", true);
   }
}
```

Try to use same sign, if you set with `"` sign then get with `"` sign instead of `'`.